# Extracting text strings from excel using new line as delimter in vbscript

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a cell in an Excel sheet which has text strings formatted as shown below:

> Section1:
>   1.Some text string
>   2. Another text string

*''A new line in excel separating two sections''*

> 1.Section 2 start here
>   2. Another text string from section 2

I used this code to extract section1 and section2 by using regular expressions (Remember match) :

```
RE.pattern = "(^Section1:\s.*\w)[\s]+(1\..*[\w]+$)"
RE.Global = True
RE.IgnoreCase = True
For iCnt = 1 To 2
  arrStr(iCnt-1) = re.Replace(str, "$"&iCnt)
  WScript.Echo arrStr(iCnt-1)
Next
```

But the output for the first remember match is showing all content(Section1 and Section2) of the cell. Please help me understand how I can parse section1 and section2 separately.

Comment: `.*` is greedy.  It's parsing a lot further than you think. Try to replace it with `.*?`

Comment: replaced .* with .*?, but have the same result.

Comment: `^([\w\W]*?)\n\n+([\w\W]+)` seems to work, try it at http://regex101.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RE.pattern = "([\w\W]+?)\n\n+([\w\W]+)"
```

is the simplest pattern that will split text separated by one or more blank lines.